# "Wrong or missing parameter value: Input layers"

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I get this error message when I try p. ex. merge layers (native or SAGA algorithm) or package layers (processing) into  geopackage. When I set files from a directory I don't have this problem.

Am I missing some configuration? I've tried short paths, layernames without space...

Linux Mint 19.2 - QGIS 3.10.1

[image]

Comment: Same with 3.10.1 under Windows 10. Time to file a bug on GitHub...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that this issue is caused by an incompatibility between QGIS and SNAIL by pblottiere.

GitHub issue here:
https://github.com/pblottiere/snail/issues/7

*Archived*

```
GitHub bug filed:  
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/33307

Work-around:  
Attempt to run the Merge tool, let it fail.  
Close the tool, and then re-open a new instance of the Merge tool.  
Try adding the layers from the layer list.  
Re-run the tool.  

It worked for me repeatably this way.
```

Comment: I can't reproduce it here. Using Linux Mint 19.2.

Comment: So the work-around does not work for you? Hmm

Comment: No. Reopen tool and try again after first try returns same error.

Comment: I didn't experience the issue on QGIS master, so it should likely be fixed soon. Can you try master?

Comment: OK. Don't have much experience compile master version. I'll try. Maybe using VM.

Comment: Don't mess up your install. There should be a fix released soon.

Comment: Do you have the SNAIL plugin by pblottiere installed?

Comment: Yes. Assuming that could be a problem I uninstalled extension and its dependency 'python3-pyqt5.qtquick'. After that there was no more error. So, it is a plugin conflict. Already tested in two different computers. Thank you for helping.

Comment: I've filed a bug report with pblottiere.
Add your feedback/comment there?
https://github.com/pblottiere/snail/issues/7